# Extended Events filtering

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I am trying to create a trace in Extended Events filtering with logins, in profiler we can filter with login names but I do not see that option in XE. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

In SQL 2016 there are 5 filter predicates you can use to filter logins.
For NT login/user you can use all 5 but SQL login/user you can use number 3,4 and 5 only.

1. sqlserver.nt_username-Collect NT username
2. sqlserver.session_nt_username-Get the current session NT user
3. sqlserver.server_principal_name-Get the name of the Server Principal in whose context the event is being fired.
4. sqlserver.username-Get the current username
5. sqlserver.session_server_principal_name-Get the name of the Server    Principal that originated the session in which the event is being    fired.

Using tsql, you need to change my code depending on  what kind of account and real value you are using.

```
    ALTER EVENT SESSION [test] ON SERVER 
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed(
     WHERE ((((([sqlserver].[username]=N'') 
       AND ([sqlserver].[session_server_principal_name]=N'')) 
       AND ([sqlserver].[server_principal_name]=N'')) 
       AND ([sqlserver].[session_nt_user]=N'')) 
       AND ([sqlserver].[session_server_principal_name]=N'')))
    GO
```

From GUI:

Once you pick select events, highlight event and click configure.

[image]

Under filter set your And/or condition, filed, operator, value.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reference anywhere for what those different fields are?

Comment: I am not aware of, other than the description within the GUI. I remember doing some testing while answering this question. What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Just wondering which of all these fields I need. What’s the difference? Presumably some are populated with windows vs sql auth … but then what?

Comment: ie the subtleties between the different fields aren’t immediately obvious, to me at least. Would be great to see some examples of when they’re different from each other & what values they have in different cases to make it more obvious which to choose.